# How to use: ido-find-file in an elisp function?

Tags: elisp

I wanted to write a script that required a filename as an argument.
I wanted to leverage 'ido-find-file' to get the file, since it's such
a nice way to select a filename, but I didn't want to open the file
as such, just use it as the argument to my function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ido-find-file` internally uses `ido-read-file-name` to ask for the file path in the minibuffer.

You can use it like this:

```
(ido-read-file-name "my prompt: ")
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use `read-file-name`.  This will use IDO's method if IDO is enabled (i.e. if the user likes IDO) and will use another method if the user prefers the other method.

Comment: I do have ido installed and this didn't work, tho Francesco's version did?

Comment: the standard `read-file-name` function only uses ido's implementation if `ido-everywhere` is activated. You can add something like `(ido-everywhere 1)` in your init file for this to work.